# How to trigger the windows task scheduler event when my computer's CPU is overrun over 30 minutes?

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

my computer's OS is windows 7, I would like to do this: when my computer's CPU is overrun over 30 minutes, it will trigger task scheduler's event which is send a email to my email account. I don't know how to do this, anyone know it? Thank you for all your kind attention and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Use Performance monitor and create an alert for high CPU usage. No programming is needed. (This belongs to Serverfault/Superuser IMHO).

Comment: If I only use Performance monitor, it can only send a email when the CPU usage is overrun, it means that if my computer's CPU is overrun 30 minutes, it will send many emails to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult dealing with a foreign language. I am sure you are doing better than I would with your language.

Assuming you want to send an email if a particular process has been running for more than 30 minutes CPU time,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: get list of tasks which have run more than (time)
SET "overrun="
FOR /f %%i IN ('TASKLIST /fi "cputime gt 00:30:00" ^|FIND /i "dnetc.exe" ') DO SET overrun=Y
IF DEFINED overrun ECHO generate your overrun email
```

Just change the time to suit and the executable name as required.

Schedule this batch to run as often as you see fit - say every 40 minutes or whatever.

As for how you'd actually send the email, I use `BLAT`